# How to send a post request to a php server on my Mac via my iOS application?

Tags: php, ios, post

I am writing an ios application that needs to send post requests to a php server. The server is in my localhost and its address is `Macintosh HD\Applications\MAMP\htdocs\amniat\server_2.php`

in my application in xcode, I have the code:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://192.168.128.251/amniat/server_2.php"]];
    [request setValue:@"*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"voice=%@",data] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else {
        //success
        NSLog(@"Succeess");
    }
```

where `192.168.128.251` is my current ip.

when I run the code, I always get a `can not connect to server`  exception.

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you ping your Mac ? i.e. Did you already rule out network issues?

Comment: Can you browse to the URL from Safari on your device?

Comment: @Paulw11 no i can not :|. `Safari Can Not Connect To Server` appears

Comment: @LorenzMeyer yeah I can ping my ip

Comment: Then it is possible that your server isn't listening on that port/IP address or that the firewall is blocking the connection.  Is your web server configured to port 80?